# Node - callbacks stop working with large arrays

Tags: arrays, node.js

I'm working with an array of about 28,000 rather large objects in a node.js application. For some reason, the final module of this data processing task is never called when I'm above about 10,000 items in the array - it simply hangs at the end. If I splice the array to around 1 or 2 thousand objects, it works perfectly.

I'm very lost. I've been staring at this bug for a while. I initially thought it was [a bug with q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/issues/621) but after trying the proposed solution to q, and replacing q with async, the execution still comes to a halt.

The code essentially looks like this:

*main.js*

```
var task1 = require('task1');
var buggyTask = require('task2');
var notCalledTask = require('task3');

return task1().then(buggyTask).then(notCalledTask);
```

*buggyTask.js*

```
module.exports = function(items) {
    var updateOrInsertData = function(item) {
        return Q(Item.create(item));
    };
    return Q.all(items.map(updateOrInsertData));
};
```

I should add that the program is definitely not running out of memory. I'm running it with `--max-old-space-size=4096`

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting a final callback before reaching node's `max-stack-size`?

Comment: wouldn't node throw an error or something?

Comment: I have been through a similar case, and in my case node did not throw any errors, it just hanged and the solution was to increase the `max-stack-size` (or `stack-size` if you are using v0.10.x)

Comment: Also, the weirdest part is that when it doesn't work, it will finish the sub-task (I.e. Updating data) of _buggyTask_ before failing to proceed regardless of the amount of data. So whether it's 10k or 28k documents it'll process them all and then just not move on

Comment: Sounds like you might have an interesting answer though. I just left my computer but add it as an answer I'll try it in a few hrs

Comment: I cannot put this as an answer as i am not 100% sure that this is the solution for your problem, an answer should be a 100% accurate answer, if this solved your problem then you might up-vote my comments.

Comment: If you have that many elements, have you tried avoiding using Q and/or replacing convenience functions like `.map()` with a for-loop, to see how it affects performance?

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash how large would you recommend I extend the stack size to? I have 4096 mb of memory allocated for the process so I can make it pretty large; just not sure what a good test number would be

Comment: hmm no dice on expanding the stack size to --stack-size=10000...and @mscdex the issue isn't performance though, so i'm not sure how that would help. I use a lot of .maps and .filters in the project so removing them all would be quite a pain

Comment: Hmm, I just tried splitting the load up into 500 item chunks, and the whole process just stops at 8000 items now. This is super weird and frustrating

Comment: @JasonMarmon What do you use to get your job done, async or Q?

Comment: I use Q for the most part, but switched to async under the consideration it might be an issue with concurrency in Q. As it turns out, none of this was the case, and it was some type of issue with mongodb that i'm still investingating. we opened a fresh database and it worked perfectly. very odd.

Comment: Does the problematic database have indexes setup on the involved collections?